# jQuery html() not working in IE after ajax() call which returns html5

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, find

I have this code:

```
$(function(){



    $('body').append('<div id="tooltipMaterials"><span id="arrow"></span><div id="inside"></div></div');
                var $tooltip = $('#tooltipMaterials');
                $tooltip.hide();
                $('.material a').mouseenter(function(){
                    var index = $(this).index();
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var top = offset.top+46;
                    var left = offset.left-$tooltip.width()+46;
                    $tooltip.css({top:top+'px',left:left+'px'});
                    $tooltip.children('#inside').empty();
                    $tooltip.prepend('<span id="preloader"></span>');
                    $tooltip.fadeIn(200);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'materials.htm',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        cache: false,
                        error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                            alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
                        }, 
                        success:function(data){
                            $('#preloader').remove();
                            alert(data);
                            alert($(data).find('.item:eq('+index+')').html());
                            $tooltip.children('#inside').html($(data).find('.item:eq('+index+')'));
                        }

                    });
                }).mouseleave(function(){
                    $tooltip.hide();
                }).click(function(){return false;});
            });
```

In IE the find doesn't work. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: yeah same issue i faced, then i use filter and it works.

Comment: Changed it to filter with no luck...

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If you need to, you can make AJAX work by using `type: 'post'`, `url:'/echo/html/'`, and `data:{'html': '<div>whatever you put here will be sent back</div>'}`.

Comment: Actually after some tests the find() is working. the html() has the problem

Comment: Well the problem is that I am trying to get an html5 document....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well the problem is that I am trying
>   to get an html5 document....

That, combined with the fact you're talking about Internet Explorer explains it.

This should tell you everything you need to know:

http://jdbartlett.github.com/innershiv/

> However, the shiv doesn't work in
>   Internet Explorer when an element's
>   content is added with innerHTML before
>   being appended to the document. That's
>   a common use case, and **noticeable in
>   libraries like jQuery when you try to
>   append or load (etc.) HTML5 content.**

Another resource with a nice explanation: http://css-tricks.com/html5-innershiv/